# i want key along with value like Barcode:null like this from below json value

Tags: android-studio

{
    "Barcode": null,
    "Brand": null,
    "Color": "RED",
    "Department": null,
    "Depth": 0,
    "DueDate": null,
    "Height": 0,
    "Innerqty": 1000,
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsBuyOutOfStock": false,
    "IsNew": false,
    "IsOutOfStock": false,
    "IsSpecialOffer": false,
    "IsVatApply": false,
    "Isbestdeal": false,
    "ItemType": 1,
    "MSRP": null,
    "MainBigThumb": null,
    "MainImage": null,
    "MainSmallImages": null,
    "Offerprice": 0,
    "Outerqty": 100,
    "Price": 1000,
    "PriceBand": null,
    "ProductDescription": "

Product Description</p>\r\n",
    "ProductDescription3": "

Product Description3</p>\r\n",
    "ProductDescription4": "

Product Description4</p>\r\n",
    "ProductGroupCode": null,
    "ProductImage1_Large": null,
    "ProductImage2": null,
    "ProductImage2_Large": null,
    "ProductImage2_Thumb": null,
    "ProductImage3": null,
    "ProductImage3_Large": null,
    "ProductImage3_Thumb": null,
    "ProductSummary": "Product Summary",
    "ProductVisiblity": "All",
    "Productcode": "Multi-00007",
    "RRP": 1000,
    "Size": "XL",
    "Sku_Description": "Multi-000072",
    "StockDate": null,
    "StockKeepingunit": "Multi-000072_2",
    "StockQty": 100,
    "Supplier": null,
    "SupplierPartNumber": null,
    "Tax_Code": null,
    "Thumbnail": null,
    "UPC": null,
    "UnitOfSale": null,
    "VatProductPostingGroup": null,
    "Vat_Percentage": 10,
    "Weight": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "isProductConfigurable": false,
    "IndexNumber": null,
    "Web1_Category": null,
    "Web1_Category_1": null,
    "Web1_Category_2": null,
    "Web2_Category": null,
    "Web2_Category_1": null,
    "Web2_Category_2": null,
    "Web_Category": "",
    "Web_Category_1": "",
    "Web_Category_2": ""
} {
    "Barcode": null,
    "Brand": null,
    "Color": "RED",
    "Department": null,
    "Depth": 0,
    "DueDate": null,
    "Height": 0,
    "Innerqty": 1000,
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsBuyOutOfStock": false,
    "IsNew": false,
    "IsOutOfStock": false,
    "IsSpecialOffer": false,
    "IsVatApply": false,
    "Isbestdeal": false,
    "ItemType": 1,
    "MSRP": null,
    "MainBigThumb": "rsz_390b37be04c34a7099951612b09b0efa.jpg",
    "MainImage": "rsz_e4217163f7eb401b9204c4543110925a.jpg",
    "MainSmallImages": "rsz_275e5e51603c49b2ac21ed023965544c.jpg",
    "Offerprice": 0,
    "Outerqty": 100,
    "Price": 1000,
    "PriceBand": null,
    "ProductDescription": "

Product Description</p>\r\n",
    "ProductDescription3": "

Product Description3</p>\r\n",
    "ProductDescription4": "

Product Description4</p>\r\n",
    "ProductGroupCode": null,
    "ProductImage1_Large": "rsz_60f8111b3605457d9f971cf0f60b15f1.jpg",
    "ProductImage2": "rsz_d88eb3ba241a4e60b9b77a46b9165551.jpg",
    "ProductImage2_Large": "rsz_1617bb90f96e41a4925bac2a483d32d1.jpg",
    "ProductImage2_Thumb": "rsz_e57028cc675d4ccdb63640b685447390.jpg",
    "ProductImage3": "rsz_c5d14b3239e348d7a970fa3be583647c.jpg",
    "ProductImage3_Large": "rsz_b9021dde26c6455a95e7849ee795ca1a.jpg",
    "ProductImage3_Thumb": "rsz_b8cd1eb8c9e84593b9e69feb6ce6c8dd.jpg",
    "ProductSummary": "Product Summary",
    "ProductVisiblity": "All",
    "Productcode": "Multi-00007",
    "RRP": 1000,
    "Size": "XL",
    "Sku_Description": "Multi-000072",
    "StockDate": null,
    "StockKeepingunit": "Multi-000072",
    "StockQty": 100,
    "Supplier": null,
    "SupplierPartNumber": null,
    "Tax_Code": null,
    "Thumbnail": "rsz_6a67f865f3e44fdea309cd672145193e.jpg",
    "UPC": null,
    "UnitOfSale": null,
    "VatProductPostingGroup": null,
    "Vat_Percentage": 10,
    "Weight": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "isProductConfigurable": false,
    "IndexNumber": null,
    "Web1_Category": null,
    "Web1_Category_1": null,
    "Web1_Category_2": null,
    "Web2_Category": null,
    "Web2_Category_1": null,
    "Web2_Category_2": null,
    "Web_Category": "",
    "Web_Category_1": "",
    "Web_Category_2": ""
} {
    "Barcode": null,
    "Brand": null,
    "Color": "RED",
    "Department": null,
    "Depth": 0,
    "DueDate": null,
    "Height": 0,
    "Innerqty": 1000,
    "IsActive": true,
    "IsBuyOutOfStock": false,
    "IsNew": false,
    "IsOutOfStock": false,
    "IsSpecialOffer": false,
    "IsVatApply": false,
    "Isbestdeal": false,
    "ItemType": 1,
    "MSRP": null,
    "MainBigThumb": null,
    "MainImage": null,
    "MainSmallImages": null,
    "Offerprice": 0,
    "Outerqty": 100,
    "Price": 1000,
    "PriceBand": null,
    "ProductDescription": "

Product Description</p>\r\n",
    "ProductDescription3": "

Product Description3</p>\r\n",
    "ProductDescription4": "

Product Description4</p>\r\n",
    "ProductGroupCode": null,
    "ProductImage1_Large": null,
    "ProductImage2": null,
    "ProductImage2_Large": null,
    "ProductImage2_Thumb": null,
    "ProductImage3": null,
    "ProductImage3_Large": null,
    "ProductImage3_Thumb": null,
    "ProductSummary": "Product Summary",
    "ProductVisiblity": "All",
    "Productcode": "Multi-00007",
    "RRP": 1000,
    "Size": "XL",
    "Sku_Description": "Multi-000072",
    "StockDate": null,
    "StockKeepingunit": "Multi-000072_2",
    "StockQty": 100,
    "Supplier": null,
    "SupplierPartNumber": null,
    "Tax_Code": null,
    "Thumbnail": null,
    "UPC": null,
    "UnitOfSale": null,
    "VatProductPostingGroup": null,
    "Vat_Percentage": 10,
    "Weight": 0,
    "Width": 0,
    "isProductConfigurable": false,
    "IndexNumber": null,
    "Web1_Category": null,
    "Web1_Category_1": null,
    "Web1_Category_2": null,
    "Web2_Category": null,
    "Web2_Category_1": null,
    "Web2_Category_2": null,
    "Web_Category": "",
    "Web_Category_1": "",
    "Web_Category_2": ""
}

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
String json = "[{ Barcode: 5022481129341, Brand: new, Color: null, }] ";
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
        ArrayList<String> keyArray = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i<jsonObject.names().length(); i++){
            Log.v("", "key = " + jsonObject.names().getString(i) + " value = " + jsonObject.get(jsonObject.names().getString(i)));
            keyArray.add(jsonObject.names().getString(i) + " : " + jsonObject.get(jsonObject.names().getString(i)));
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: by the help of  above code i'ii only get all key but i also want values along with key...

Comment: so basically you want "key:value" as each array item?

Comment: yes i want key:value for each like Barcode:5483473 and Brand:new etc.

Comment: check and acknowledge the answer.